# Unresolved reference:ActivityMainBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, android-data-binding

Искал решение этой проблемы в интернете, но решение, которое мне подошло, отличалось от всего, что я нагуглил, поэтому публикую этот вопрос.

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
            android:name="com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.StringFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</layout>
```

`build.gradle(Module)`:

```
android {

...

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: используйте FragmentContainerView вместо <fragment

Answer (score -1):

Дело было в разметке, а конкретно в

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
    android:name="com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.StringFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Чтобы заработало корректно, этот элемент нужно обернуть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
                android:name="com.sem.daggersimple.presentation.StringFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
            </FrameLayout>
    
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    </layout>
```

P.S. Вероятно, способы "обёртки" могут отличаться, я опубликовал то, что подошло мне в моей ситуации